# Checking file exiting in user system or not when user opens a url on his browser

Tags: javascript, php, file

I want to check whether a file with particular name and location exists in user's desktop or not when user clicks a url from browser. For example when user opens url example.com it will detect whether c://test.txt exists or not.

Comment: js has no access to filesystem - would be a huge security issue

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: No, there isn't another way to have that huge security issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you need to do, you could ask the user to upload a file, and then access their selection. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/. You could even do that without having to actually upload the file, though this would probably be confusing from a UI perspective.

Alternately, you could use the local storage that the browser has if you just need access to some kind of storage.

But the simplest answer to what you're asking is "it's not possible", if you're hoping for it to be automatic with real access to the filesystem. JavaScript in the browser is just not trusted enough to access the user's file system without users taking explicit and obvious actions.

Answer (score 3):

Cannot be done. Would be a gaping security hole.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Javascript cannot access the client's filesystem. Even if you requested that the user upload a file, you cannot detect the `path/to/the/file.txt`.

(Even though there was going to be an API for it, [it should now be considered dead](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).)